# Trouble storing value of drop down, and using in query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am having trouble getting this to store the value when submitted and then using it in my next query.  The drop down is populated fine, but it is either not storing the value or the way I am using it dynamically in my query is wrong.  Any help is appreciated.  I know I am probably missing something obvious or small, I am new to php.

drop down box

```
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT WEEK FROM Player_Points_2013");
  //$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth->execute();

echo '<form method="POST" action=" " >';
echo '<select id="week" name="week"><OPTION>';
echo "Select a Week to see the stats</OPTION>";

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo "<option value=\"$WEEK\">" . $row['WEEK'] . "</option>";
}
echo '</SELECT>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="table_stats" value="Submit"/>';
echo '</form>';

$select_val = $_POST['week'];
```

//use value from drop down to display weeks stats

```
if(isset($_POST['table_stats'])){
  $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT PName,CombinedPoints FROM `Player_Points_2013`  WHERE

    WEEK = '$select_val' ORDER BY CombinedPoints ");
    //$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sql->execute();
    Print "<table border cellpadding=10 width=500>"; 
    Print "<tr><th>Player</th><th>Points</th></tr>"; 
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 { 

 Print " <td>".$row['PName'] . "</td> ";
 Print " <td>".$row['CombinedPoints'] . "</td> </tr>";

 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
}
else {
echo $select_val;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `$row` or `$info` but not both, e.g.:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{ 

    Print " <td>".$row['PName'] . "</td> ";
    Print " <td>".$row['CombinedPoints'] . "</td> </tr>";

}
```

Also you have code:

```
echo "<option value=\"$WEEK\">" . $row['WEEK'] . "</option>";
```

What is `$WEEK`? Maybe it should be `$row['WEEK']` instead?

Comment: Thanks cant believe i did that, I'll edit my code to reflect this.  Still not displaying data though.

Comment: What exactly wrong - you have empty table or what? Did you check `$row` value? What's in it?

Comment: Double checked table it is populated, and fields are spelled correctly.  Right now it is outputting the <table><tr><th></tr></th></table> but that's it.. it's empty.  looks like nothing is being stored in $row.

Comment: Then check value of `$select_val`, echo query text and run it in phpMyAdmin for example. And once again - `var_dump($row)`

Comment: $select_val is returning nothing, and var_dump($row) is returning bool(false)

Comment: echo "<option value= '{$row['WEEK']}'" . $row['WEEK'] . "</option>";
Is working, but now the drop down is not displaying the weeks.

Comment: Where is `>`? `echo "<option value='" . $row['WEEK'] . "'>" . $row['WEEK'] . "</option>"`;

Comment: That fixed it!!  Thank you!
echo "<option value= '{$row['WEEK']}'" . "'>" . $row['WEEK'] . "</option>";
can you explain what that does?

Comment: `>` just a closing element for `<option>`. Without `>` browser can't parse `<option>`-tag properly.